# Flux from cube: Relation between the vector field to that of the opposite side

Tags: calculus

This is an exerpt from Feynman's lecture:

> . . .We wish to find the flux of a vector field $C$ through the surface of the cube. . . First consider the face  having edges $\Delta y \quad \& \quad \Delta z$. The flux outward on this face is the negative of the x-component of $C$ ,integrated over the surface. This flux is $-\int C_x dy dz$ . Since, we are considering a small cube, we can approximate this integral by the value of $C_x$ at the center of the face- which we call point (1) - multiplied by the area of the face. Therefore flux out of the face $$ = - C_x(1) \Delta y \Delta z$$. Similarly , flux from the opposite face $$= C_x(2) \Delta y \Delta z$$. Now, $C_x(1) \quad \& \quad C_x(2)$ are, in general, **slightly different.** If $\Delta x$ is small enough we can write $$ C_x(2) = C_x(1) + \dfrac{\partial C_x}{\partial x} .\Delta x$$. There are, of course , more terms but they will involve ${\left(\Delta x \right)}^2$ and higher power & so will be negligible. . .

My questions are :

1) Why are $C_x(1)$ & $C_x(2)$ **slightly different**? What did Feynman want to mean?

2) Both the values can be related by Fundamental theorem of Calulus ie. their difference is equal to the rate of change of $C$ multiplied by $\Delta x$. From where does any higher power of $\Delta x$  ie. ${\left(\Delta x \right)}^2$ ,as told by Feynman, emanate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) They are slightly different in the sense that the function $C(x)$ (or $\vec C(\vec r)$) has different values at different places in space, and so even though the two opposite faces of the cube are *very* close the value of the function $C$ at the two faces will be slightly different.

2) Only if the two points are infinitesimally close or the function $C$ is linear can you say exactly that the difference is equal to the rate of change of $C$ times $\Delta x$, but if neither of these is the case we have to allow for it by, for example as Feynman has done, using a Taylor series expansion of the unknown $C$ about a certain point, here the point labelled (1). This will give higher orders in $\Delta x$ as he has stated.

Comment: Sir, I thought fundamental theorem of calculus can be applied to any function; is then it limited to only linear function?? BTW, can you please show me one example of Taylor expansion? I'm new to it:)

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus is not really relevant here, and you can only say that the change in $C$ is *exactly* the same as the gradient times the change in $x$ in the *limit* when the change in $x$ goes to 0 (i.e. infinitesimal), OR if you happen to know that the function is linear, in which case it doesn't matter about the size of $\Delta x$. We allow for the difference to be finite first and use a Taylor expansion (example later) to capture (in principle) all the dependence on $\Delta x$, and *then* take the limit, which results in a linear form.

Comment: The Taylor expansion of a function $f(x)$ about a point $x=a$ is given by the (infinite) series: $$f(x) = f(a)+f'(a)(x-a) + {f''(a)\over 2!}(x-a)^2+{f'''(a)\over 3!}(x-a)^3+...$$ For this problem we use $f=C$ and $x-a=\Delta x$.